# If statement using RegEx in Ruby (Chef recipe)

Tags: ruby, regex, if-statement, chef-infra

I have a Chef recipe in which I'm trying to say:

> "If the server's hostname ends in -1, then enable and start the newrelic-sysmond and newrelic-daemon services, else, disable those services"

using RegEx to determine whether the hostname does end in -1 or not.

Using my attempt below, the services seem to enable and start regardless of whether the hostname ends in -1 or not. I'm quite new to Ruby and Chef so I wouldn't be surprise if my code is incorrect:

```
if node["hostname"] =~ /^.*-1$/
    service 'newrelic-sysmond' do
        action [ :enable, :start ]
    end
    service 'newrelic-daemon' do
        action [ :enable, :start ]
    end
else
    service 'newrelic-sysmond' do
        action [ :disable ]
    end
    service 'newrelic-daemon' do
        action [ :disable ]
    end
end
```

Comment: Any example of the `node["hostname"]` value which match where they shouldn't ? You can add a `Chef::Log.warn "Testing hostname: #{node['hostname']}"` before your if to debug and see what it is testing. (your code seems ok to me)

Comment: And is this code the only one in your runlist ? maybe there's another place where the same service resource is defined. (in this case you should rewind it instead of redefining it, see https://docs.chef.io/dsl_recipe.html#edit-resource)

Comment: "...determine whether the hostname does end in -1..." Then use `node["hostname"].end_with?("-1")`. It's MUCH faster and clearer than your regex. If you insist on using a regex then `/-1$/` is sufficient and much clearer. See http://rubular.com/r/E5trSWP2lf and http://rubular.com/r/jVOu4hD6Re It appears your current pattern is correct so the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: @theTinMan Is String#ends_with? a Chef extension?  I don't think it's in base Ruby.

Comment: `String#end_with?` is standard Ruby.

Comment: @Wayne, [String#end_with?](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/String.html#method-i-end_with-3F) was recently introduced in v1.8.7.

Comment: My mistake.  I was typing the incorrect plural `ends_with?`, not the correct singular `end_with?`

Comment: I always mistype it as `ends_with?` the first time too. I find `end_with?` awkward grammar.

Answer (score 0):

There is a chance that the hostname isn't what you think it is. You probably want something like `if node['machinename'] =~ /-1$/` or `if node['machinename'].end_with?('-1')`. Otherwise that looks okay.

Comment: It's questionable practice to create answers based on the comments made an hour before.

Comment: The important bit was to use `machinename` instead of `hostname` which wasn't mentioned before.